# How do I integrate $\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=0$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to integrate an ODE of the form
$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=0.$$
I know I need to integrate w.r.t $x$ to create a first order ODE but I'm not sure how as the $dx$ is in the denominator.

Comment: You have that $\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=C$

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a "hack" solution, but we can multiply both sides by $x$ to find $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=0$$
Which tells us that $\text{deg}\left(x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=0$, i.e, it is a constant. So now our equation is $$x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{yx^2}{2}=C$$
$$y'+\frac{x}{2}y=\frac{C}{x}$$
This is a first order linear ordinary differential equation, so we can find solutions via the method of [Integrating Factors](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{yx^2}{2}\right)=0$$
Integration gives us:
$$xy'+\frac{yx^2}{2}=C$$
It's a first order linear DE.

---

Whenever you see this
$$\dfrac {df}{dx}=0$$
You can deduce that 
$$f=c$$
Because the only function that gives zero once you differentiate it is the constant function.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. Well done.

Comment: Thanks Oh will upvote your answer. @K.defaoite

Comment: I feel like im being daft but which rule did you use to obtain that answer? I just can't see it

Comment: @PokerF4ce You have a derivative that's equal to zero ...so you integrate and get a constant on RHS because the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: @PokerF4ce I added some lines I hope it's more clear.